# How to close a Java program without close a process started by this java program?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, process

I want to ensure that when my Java program to close, a process opened by this java will not close together. I use this to create my process:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdCommand);
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

I saw that if I run my java program as a jar in a CMD, what I want works. But when I perform this by IntelliJ executor, my opened process closes together with my java application.

Maybe the problem is not the IntelliJ, but  I suspect to be because it doesn't occur in CMD.

Can you help-me?

Comment: what is the value cmdCommand ?

Comment: It is a List<String> with the .exe filepath and an argument to this exe.